# Are "career opportunities in region X" on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to know what is the community's consensus about these kind of questions.

Currently, [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39437/what-paid-flight-opportunities-exist-for-low-hour-commercial-pilots-in-alaska) is closed. Someone suggested that we have a very similar question [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13243/what-job-opportunities-are-there-for-low-time-pilots-in-malaysia) which is currently open. So we have two questions which are nearly identical, but their on-topic/close status conflict each other.

Comment: We've also discussed [Voting to close very old questions](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2977/1696) and the consensus seems to be that even if we consider a question off topic now, we shouldn't automatically close it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

([This question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3067/62) is closely related but isn't specifically about the 'region X issue'.)

We have a few of these questions, as you said, and international aviation careers are obviously important and interesting for a lot of people. So I think it's a great idea to try to come to some consensus on what we can usefully answer here.

The questions you're talking about usually include one or more of the following points:

1. How can I use my pilot's license from country X in country Y? ([Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29613/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23928/62))
2. What qualifications does a commercial/airline pilot need in country Y? ([Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8891/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33894/62))
3. Can I legally work in country Y? ([Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13579/62))
4. Where/How can I find a job in country Y? ([Here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13243/62))

My take on them (YMMV) is:

- 1 is on topic: it's about licensing and regulations and in theory there's always an answer.
- 2 is also on topic: it's a straightforward question about licensing. Different airlines might have slightly different requirements, but we can at least answer the regulatory part.
- 3 is off topic most of the time. Working in another country is primarily about immigration and employment law, not aviation. What *might* be on topic here is a more aviation-specific question like "does airline X sponsor work visas for foreign pilots?" or just "does airline X employ foreign pilots?". That's answerable, but on the other hand the answers would become outdated if the airline's policy changes.
- 4 is off topic because it's asking for pointers to specific employers, industries, working locations etc. That's always going to be highly subjective and answers could change overnight.

I think that because career questions often combine those four points somehow, we tend to close them because of the subjective parts even if other parts of the question could be answered objectively. I don't know how best to deal with that, other than to answer what can be answered and point out that the rest is off topic (as I tried to do [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13592/62), for example). Or we could edit questions to remove or reduce the subjective parts.